# py2exe 64 bit for py2.7 installation problems

Tags: python, exe

When installing `p2exe`, I get as far as the program finding `python 2.7` in the registry, but then it says:

`py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.exe doesn't work anymore`

(originally in dutch: "werkt niet meer")

I've tried other versions of `py2exe`, but those are not compatible with `python 2.7`. how to get `p2exe` to work?

thanks,

steven

Answer (score 0):

Install pip by running this [script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and then run `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install py2exe`.

Comment: i ran the script in python idle, and i says it did not get access to description.rst . also, where do i run C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install py2exe? before i forget, thanks for replying ;)

Comment: Don't run the script from IDLE, do it from Command Prompt like so. `C:\Python27\python get-pip.py` in the appropriate folder.

Comment: im sorry, i still dont have a clue what to do. do i have to copy the script in the link and past it in cmd?

Comment: No, what version of Windows are you running?

Comment: im am running windows 8

Comment: Find the directory in which there is `get-pip.py`. Hold `Shift + Right Click`, then select `Open Command Prompt here`. Type `C:\Python27\python.exe get-pip.py`.

Comment: It should be in your Downloads folder. Open command prompt and type `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\stevensie\Dowloads\get-pip.py`. Replace stevensie with your username on the computer.